# how can i fix this "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range" errors?

Tags: c++, csv, c++14, opencsv, read.csv

I try to read some csv data, but I keep getting this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size()
> (which is 1)

customer.csv

```
id, name, address

1, "Knut", "Knutveien 3"

2, "Lise", "Liseveien 7"
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidcsv/rapidcsv.h"

using namespace std;

void read_customer()
{
    rapidcsv::SeparatorParams sp; // make a object sp
    sp.mTrim = true; // remove the line space, equal to true
    // open the customer document
    rapidcsv::Document doc_customer("customers.csv", rapidcsv::LabelParams(), sp);
    for (int i = 0; i < doc_customer.GetRowCount(); i++)
    {
        auto name = doc_customer.GetCell<string>("name", i);
        auto address = doc_customer.GetCell<string>("address", i);
        cout << "customer: " << name << ", " << address << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    read_customer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to modify the empty lines of customer.csv with `,,`.

Comment: The error is because you are accessing a `std::vector` out of bounds.  You are requesting index 1 (the 2nd element) when the `vector` only has 1 element in it (index 0). As there is no `vector` in the code shown, the error has to be in code you have not shown, so you are just going to have to [debug the code for yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: can you explain more, i dont understand what you mean by "accessing a std::  vector  out of bounds",  im just now with c++.

Comment: and i did modify  the customer.csv file but it didn't change anything.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong, and if you run it in a debugger, it will show you exact line where it happens. Already mentioned in the previous comments, but again: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The input data does not look like regular CSV data. If you remove the blank lines from the data, and change it into to something like:

```
id, name, address
1, "Knut", "Knutveien 3"
2, "Lise", "Liseveien 7"
```

before trying to read it, `rapidcsv` is able to parse it correctly.

The C++ code looks OK aside from using different filename `customers.csv` than specified in the question (`customer.csv`).

For completeness, I removed the blank lines from `customer.csv` and used the following `main.cpp` content which succefully parsed the file.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "rapidcsv.h"

void read_customer()
{
  rapidcsv:: SeparatorParams sp; // make a object sp
  sp.mTrim = true;  //remove the line space, equal to true

  // open the customer document
  rapidcsv:: Document doc_customer("customer.csv", rapidcsv::LabelParams(), sp);

  for (int i = 0; i < doc_customer.GetRowCount(); i++)
  {
    auto name =  doc_customer.GetCell<std::string>("name", i);
    auto address = doc_customer.GetCell<std::string>("address", i);
    std::cout << "customer: " << name << ", " << address << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  read_customer();  
  return 0;
}
```